# In Rundeck: how can you set the working directory for command execution?

Tags: rundeck

No matter what I try, executing `pwd` always prints `/var/log/rundeck`. I'd like to configure this as a global or even project-wide setting as all my scripts and commands will be relative to a specific directory on the file system.

`/home/jobs` for example.

Answer (score 2):

There is no setting on Rundeck can set working directory.

Each command is running in separate context, you can chain them together.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an improvement to the above answer by "Yang" you can edit rundeck "resources.xml" file and add a attribute called "nodepwd" with your node location like below.

```
<node name="localhost" nodepwd="/your/pwd/location" ....  />
```

Then you can change your path to that and execute the commands.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to run "cd $RD_NODE_NODEPWD" in my inline scripts to change the current working directory.